JUnit 5 + Mockito tests are significantly slower compared to JUnit 4 – how to optimize?
I'm migrating our tests from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, and I'm noticing a substantial increase in execution time for tests using Mockito. Specifically, empty tests take almost 100 times longer with JUnit 5.
In JUnit 4, an empty test using MockitoJUnitRunner completes in around 6ms:
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class X {

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}

However, in JUnit 5, an equivalent empty test using MockitoExtension takes approximately 600ms:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class X {

    
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }

}

Is there any way of making the Extension faster?

I doubt that the individual test with JUnit Jupiter really takes 600ms. How did you measure?
My first guess is that the JUnit framework start up (discovery + execution) takes longer with whatever you use to run your tests. If each JUnit Jupiter test with the Mockito extension really took 600ms, something would be fundamentally broken.

I took the time from Intellij. It's only the first test that takes long due to MockitoExtension Initialization

I now created an empty project to be sure using only Mocktio and junit5. The empty test still takes 600ms

Test run with mvn:
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.724 s -- in X

From what you write my interpretation is that Mockito initialization could be the problem. Any chance that the JUnit 4 MockitoRunner is using a different version of Mockito?

I used the newest and same version for all dependencies

You are measuring the JVM start and compilation of Java code, nothing more. If you execute two tests, it will take the same 600 ms. If you execute 10 tests, it will still be roughly 600 ms. Why is it important to you how long an empty test takes?
